# Weaker condition for monotony?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that if $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and: 
$$\lim\inf_{t\to t_0} \frac{f(t)-f(t_0)}{t-t_0}\geq 0, \forall t_0\in [a,b] ,$$ then $f$ is increasing on [a,b]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed the weaker condition
$$
\limsup_{t\to t_0+} \frac{f(t) - f(t_0)}{t-t_0} \geq 0,
\qquad
\forall t\in [a,b)
$$
(with $f$ continuous in $[a,b]$) is enough to prove that $f$ is a non-decreasing function.

Namely, let $x_0, x_1\in [a,b]$, $x_0 < x_1$, and let us prove that
$f(x_0)\leq f(x_1)$.
Let us consider the auxiliary function
$$
g(x) := f(x) - \frac{f(x_1) - f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}\, (x-x_0),
\qquad x\in [x_0, x_1].
$$
Since $g$ is continuous in $[x_0, x_1]$, 
by the Weierstrass' theorem it admits a maximum point $c$.
Since $g(x_0) = g(x_1)$, it is not restrictive to assume that
$c\in [x_0, x_1)$.

We clearly have
$$
\frac{g(y) - g(c)}{y-c} \leq 0
\qquad \forall y\in (c, x_1]\,,
$$
hence
$$
0 \geq \limsup_{y\to c+} \frac{g(y) - g(c)}{y-c}
= \limsup_{y\to c+} \frac{f(y) - f(c)}{y-c}
- \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}
\geq
- \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}\,,
$$
so that $f(x_0)\leq f(x_1)$.